# Read values from a spreadsheet and write XML

Tags: javascript, xml, excel

I need to substitute some lines in a series of XML files, based on the values written in a spreadsheet (Excel). Can this be done in Javascript, or is there a better route?
Thanks

Comment: Not a problem of the language, but more of the availability of a library to read Excel files.

Comment: Have you looked at being able to read excel files in javascript?

Answer (score 1):

There is at least one [Excel parser](https://npmjs.org/package/excel) for JS and [no shortage of XML parsers](https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/xml), so it is certainly possible.